# Proving a.e surjectivity of suggested factor map in Natural extension of Standard Borel dynamical system

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal B,\mu, T)$ be a measure preserving dynamical system on a standard Borel space. I'm trying to follow the construction of the natural extension by Michael Hochman on page 53 of his [notes](http://math.huji.ac.il/~mhochman/courses/ergodic-theory-2012/notes.final.pdf). This is very similar to the construction mentioned in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740796/does-any-measure-preserving-system-have-an-invertible-extension) post, which unfortunately fails to answer the one question I have about the construction.

For convenience let me repeat the essentials of the construction: We consider $X^\mathbb{Z}$, with the normal product $\sigma$ algebra $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}$, ensuring that each projection $\pi_n$ is measurable. The Kolmogorov extension theorem guarantees the existence of a probability measure $\tilde\mu$ on $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}$, such that the pushforward $\pi_{n*}\tilde\mu=\mu$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$. The left shift $\tilde T$ is invertible, measurable, and measure preserving on $(X^\mathbb{Z},\tilde{\mathcal{B}},\tilde\mu)$. Now let us define 
$$\tilde X=\{(x_n)\in X^\mathbb{Z}:Tx_n=x_{n+1},~n\in\mathbb Z\},$$
and redefine $\tilde{\mathcal{B}},\tilde\mu,$ and $\tilde T$ to be the relevant restrictions to $\tilde X^~$. Finally let us define $\pi:\tilde X\to X$ by $\pi=\pi_0|_{\tilde X}$.

The goal is to show that $\pi$ is a factor map. I am happy with showing that $\pi$ is measurable, measure preserving, and that $\pi\circ \tilde T=T\circ \pi$, but what I have been unable to do is prove that $\mu(\operatorname{im}\pi)=1$, which we need if we want to call $\pi$ a factor map. My idea is to show that the set $A$ consisting of all $x\in X$ for which there is an infinite chain in the graph of all preimages of $x$ has full measure. To be more precise: $A$ consists of all $x\in X$ such there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ in $X$ such that $Tx_{n+1}=x_n$ for all $n$, and $x_0=x$. If $A$ does have full measure then we would be done, because for every $x\in A$ it would follow that $(\dots,x_2,x_1,x,Tx,T^2x,\dots)\in \tilde X$. Now I believe that we could construct $A$ as a clever countable intersection of sets of full measure, but I am currently not clever enough to see it. If anyone can see it I'd be much obliged.

From scouring the interwebs I know that the existence of a natural extension of a dynamical system is closely related to the notion of the categorical inverse limit. Unfortunately category theory is one of the many need to be familiar with area of mathematics that I am not familiar with. I would still appreciate an answer phrased in terms of inverse limits (if it was explained in a gentle manner), because that can only help my familiarity with category theory. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\operatorname{im}\pi$ won't be measurable in general - e.g. take $X=[0,1]^3$ with uniform measure, and $\pi$ to be the identity except on $\{0\}\times [0,1]^2$ where it acts as your favourite measurable function with non-Borel image.

However, we can pick a full-measure set $S_k\subseteq \operatorname{im}T^k,$ then take the intersection. This will have full measure and infinite preimages. Take for example $S_k=\cup_n T^k(A_{k,n})$ where $A_{k,n}$ is a compact set as given by Lusin's theorem such that $\mu(A_{k,n})>1-1/n$ and $T^k$ is continuous on $A_{k,n}$ - note that $\mu(T^k(A_{k,n}))\geq \mu(A_{k,n})$ so $\mu(S_k)=1.$

Comment: Ahh yes just because $\pi$ is measurable doesn't mean it's image is. Should have caught that. Thanks though, I think this works well

Comment: Do you mind please expanding on your last statement that $\mu(T^k(A_{k,n}))\geq\mu(A_{k,n})?$ I have a feeling it might have something to do with analytic sets, but can't figure it out

Comment: @K.Power: by the measure-preserving property, $\mu(T^{-k}(T^k(A_{k,n})))=\mu(T^k(A_{k,n})).$ So the inequality is just monotonicity of measures applied to $A_{k,n}\subseteq T^{-k}(T^k(A_{k,n})).$

Comment: Simplicity is key. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I thought I followed your argument, but I now don't see how we can say that each $T^kA_{k,n}$ is Borel measurable? Because the space is standard Borel we know each $T^kA_{k,n}$ will be Lebesgue measurable, but is that enough?

Comment: @K.Power: the image of a compact set is compact hence closed hence Borel. There is a gap though - Lusin's theorem only applies to $\mathbb R$ so you need to invoke Kuratowski's theorem that an uncountable standard Borel space is Borel isomorphic to $\mathbb R.$

Comment: Oh I was thinking about the version of Lusin's theorem that I know, which only guarantees that the $A_{k,n}$ can be chosen to be closed, not necessarily compact, and so I misread your definition of them. If $X$ is locally compact though we can choose the $A_{k,n}$ exactly as you have. I wasn't originally thinking that $X$ was necessarily locally compact , but I'm happy to accept that as a condition (unless you don't actually use it in your proof, in which case I'd be curious as to how you choose compact $A_{k,n}$ then.)